# Extension, super constructor and static methods

Tags: scala

I have this class

```
class Tester(round: Int, x: Int, y: Int,sparringPartners:Array[RobotSpecification]) {
  def this(s:Array[RobotSpecification]) = {
    this(5, 800, 600, s)

  }

 def getRandomRobot(eng: RobocodeEngine): Array[RobotSpecification] = {//blabla}
}
```

and i want to extend doing something like this

```
class EasyTester() extends Tester(getRandomRobot()){}
```

Obviously it doesn't work.

Probably the problem is trivial but i'm just recently approaching the OO part of Scala so i never worked with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getRandomRobot` belongs to `Tester` logically, but doesn't depend on the state of a tester, you can turn it into a method on a [companion](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/basics2.html#object) object:

```
object Tester {
    def getRandomRobot(eng: RobocodeEngine): Array[RobotSpecification] = { ... }
}
```

One way would be just to pass `sparringPartners` into `EasyTester`'s constructor:

```
class EasyTester(sparringPartners: Array[RobotSpecification]) extends Tester(sparringPartners) { ... }

import Tester._
val eng = ...
val easyTester = new EasyTester(getRandomRobot(eng))
```

To make the instantiation simpler than that, `EasyTester` could have a companion object with an `apply` method that instantiates it:

```
import Tester._
object EasyTester {
    def apply(implicit eng: RobocodeEngine) = {
      new EasyTester(getRandomRobot(eng))
   }
}

implicit val eng: RobocodeEngine = ...
val easyTester = EasyTester
```